# PouchDB - Compaction mode

Tags: pouchdb

1. I could create a database in compaction mode when underlying database API was IndexedDB. But I can still see the revision details of those documents. For us, maintaining these revision numbers is also unnecessary storage waste, and we want to get rid of these as well. If a document is deleted then we completely want to get rid of all the details of the deleted document. 
   Is there any way, please let me know.
2. When trying to create a database in compaction mode when underlying database API is WebSQL then get below error. Is it not compatible or I am missing something.

Code:   var dbWebSqlCompact2 = new PouchDB('dbWebSqlCompact2', {adapter : 'websql'}, {auto_compaction: true});

Error:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a function {stack: (...), message: "object is not a function"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) That is the `purge()` feature, it's not implemented yet: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802

2) If you're not in Chrome or Safari, then yes, WebSQL is not supported: http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser

Comment: Thanks Nolan for your inputs.<br/>
#1. Ok, thanks for info.<br/>
#2. I tried same in Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89. And as we know it has WebSQL supprrt. I think there could be a problem during fallback when using "auto_compaction" attribute because when I remove this attribute then it works fine and I Can see store created in WebSQL.